# MySQL Erratic Query Times

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL version 5.5.14 to run the following query from a table of 5 Million rows:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Type, P.Name, P.cty
     , X(P.latlng) as 'lat', Y(P.latlng) as 'lng'
     , P.cur, P.ak, P.tn, P.St, P.Tm, P.flA, P.ldA, P.flN
     , P.lv, P.bd, P.bt, P.nb
     , P.ak * E.usD as 'usP' 
FROM PIG P 
  INNER JOIN EEL E 
    ON E.cur = P.cur 
WHERE act='1' 
  AND flA >= '1615' 
  AND ldA >= '0' 
  AND yr >= (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) 
  AND lv >= '0' 
  AND bd >= '3' 
  AND bt >= '2' 
  AND nb <= '5' 
  AND cDate >= NOW() 
  AND MBRContains(LineString( Point(-65.6583, -87.8906)
                            , Point(65.6583, 87.8906)
                            ), latlng) 
  AND Type = 'g' 
  AND tn = 'l' 
  AND St + Tm - YEAR(NOW()) >= '30' 
HAVING usP BETWEEN 300/2 AND 300 LIMIT 100;
```

**On the first occasion, it took 313s, on the second occasion it took 48s and on the third occasion it took 101s.** From explain select, the query plan has type: range; key: index and extra: using where on table P followed by type: eq_ref and key: primary on table E. This query does not use query cache. My question is: **"Why is the query time so dramatically different?"**

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: The question is pretty valid. But shouldn't you be more concerned as to why the query times are so big? (and how to make them small)?

Comment: Yes, I am also concerned about that and was wondering if the erratic query time is linked to performance as well.

Comment: Is it a production system? Were there other queries runnning the same time as these tests?

Comment: My query time for fourth trial 56s, fifth trial 2s, sixth trial 2s. Amazing... No cache involved since there is a NOw() function in my query.

Comment: This is a test setup. No other queries running besides this one.

Comment: Besides the query cache, there are other internal caches that can be used (and probbaly are in this case). Index cache (most recently used B-tree index blocks) is a candidate for this behaviour.

Comment: If you run other, different queries for a period, and then run again this one, and the time is long again, then this is the cause. The cache (like index cache) will be flushed out of memory if memory is needed for other queries. Then, when you run it again, the indexes have to be loaded again from disk.

Comment: Check this blog. It answers the exact same question like yours: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/09/12/query-profiling-with-mysql-bypassing-caches/ with many details regarding different engines, OS and hardware caches.

Comment: Do you mean that the long query time is actually due to the loading of index to memory from disk? Does that means that every time after I flush the system's page cache, the long query time will occur?

Comment: By system page cache you are referring to the OS cache. I was referring to the index cache (InnoDB and MyISAM have Innodb Buffer Pool and Key Buffer respectively). There is also the table metadata which has to be loaded (if not in table cache). So, yes, I mean that the long query times when you run it first time or after a period of running other queries is due to having to load all (or some of this) from disk to memory.

Comment: I see.. Seems there are many different forms of cache at work. Since my select query is constantly changing, the cache is as good as none. I would tend to expect similar slow query times every time. I am not sure if 300s is considered reasonable time for 5 million rows.

Comment: If they are MyISAM tables, try `SET global key_buffer_size=0;` to see if the Key Buffer is being used.

Comment: For improving performance, I think you should make a new question. Include tables' definitions and execution plan.

Comment: I tried Set global key_buffer_size=0; and it gives me an error: ERROR 1438 (HY000): Cannot drop default keycache. I did a flush tables command and the query time is long for the first time but below 2s for subsequent queries, same effect as flushing the system's page cache.

Comment: The 'SET global key_buffer_size=0;' still does not work. I read that "By default, table indexes are assigned to the main (default) key cache created at the server startup." [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cache-index.html) I will make a separate post with regards to improving the performance.

Comment: `SET global key_buffer_size=8; SET global key_buffer_size=DEFAULT;` I see in the docs that minimum is `8`. It was `0` in older versions.

Comment: I got the same error as before. I have posted a new question on performance optimisation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432255/mysql-enhancing-performance-without-cache)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) when profiling queries:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE P.ID, P.Type, ...
```

The reason it takes less times on the second run is that the result of the query has been cached by MySQL.

SQL_NO_CACHE disables caching for this query. You can clear the query cache with `FLUSH QUERY CACHE`.

Comment: MySQL does not cache query that involves the use of NOW() function. [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html)

Comment: I have further confirmed that my status variable qcache_queries_in_cache is 0.

Comment: Then it may be the system's page cache

Comment: How do I check the system's page cache? I have been monitoring my CPU, memory and swap history. No visible spikes on memory and swap. Spikes for CPU when query times are fast, no spikes when query times are slow.

Comment: I tried and query time did become longer. Seems the system's page cache is at work.

Comment: The second and subsequent query are all within 2s