# MySQL Enhancing Performance without Cache

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL version 5.5.14 to run the following query from a table of 5 Million rows:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Type, P.Name, P.cty
     , X(P.latlng) as 'lat', Y(P.latlng) as 'lng'
     , P.cur, P.ak, P.tn, P.St, P.Tm, P.flA, P.ldA, P.flN
     , P.lv, P.bd, P.bt, P.nb
     , P.ak * E.usD as 'usP' 
FROM PIG P 
  INNER JOIN EEL E 
    ON E.cur = P.cur 
WHERE act='1' 
  AND flA >= '1615' 
  AND ldA >= '0' 
  AND yr >= (YEAR(NOW()) - 100) 
  AND lv >= '0' 
  AND bd >= '3' 
  AND bt >= '2' 
  AND nb <= '5' 
  AND cDate >= NOW() 
  AND MBRContains(LineString( Point(-65.6583, -87.8906)
                            , Point(65.6583, 87.8906)
                            ), latlng) 
  AND Type = 'g' 
  AND tn = 'l' 
  AND St + Tm - YEAR(NOW()) >= '30' 
HAVING usP BETWEEN 300/2 AND 300 LIMIT 100;
```

The table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE `PIG` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Email` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `Type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Name` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cty` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latlng` point NOT NULL,
  `tn` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'l',
  `St` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Tm` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `yr` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flA` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ldA` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flN` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lv` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bd` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bt` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nb` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '9',
  `cur` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ak` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Des` tinytext,
  `pDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `act` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ab` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `id_ca` (`cty`,`ak`),
  SPATIAL KEY `id_latlng` (`latlng`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `EEL` (
  `cur` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `usD` decimal(11,10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cur`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The following shows the query execution plan:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: P
         type: range
possible_keys: id_latlng
          key: id_latlng
      key_len: 34
          ref: NULL
         rows: 742873
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: E
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: BS.P.cur
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

This query does not use query cache due to the presence of NOW() function. From my previous [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429336/mysql-erratic-query-times), I discovered that other forms of cache exist to speed up the query from initial time of **300s down to less than 2s**. My question is: "**how does one improve the above query time, knowing that the cache won't be of much use since the search criteria for latlng is constantly changing?**" Note that a spatial index on latlng has already been built for optimisation purpose.

Cheers, Ben

Comment: Would it be possible to replace now() with a fixed date-time, as a parameter for example? You would be able to use the cache depending on the precision of your date-time.

Comment: use `EXPLAIN ... \G`* for better readability ;)

Comment: @Colin, I can change the NOW() to CURDATE() but CURDATE() is non-cacheable too.

Answer (score 0):

Good indexes are the ones with high selectivity. Your conditions are mostly range conditions and this poses a limit on the fields that can be used in a composite index.

Possible indexes to investigate (composed from those fields that have an equality check with the addition in the end, of one field with a range check):

```
(act, Type, tn, flA)

(act, Type, tn, cDate)

(act, Type, tn, nb)
```

To check selectivity without creating indexes, you could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PIG P 
WHERE act='1' 
  AND Type = 'g' 
  AND tn = 'l' 
  AND flA >= '1615'
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PIG P 
WHERE act='1' 
  AND Type = 'g' 
  AND tn = 'l' 
  AND cDate >= NOW()
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PIG P 
WHERE act='1' 
  AND Type = 'g' 
  AND tn = 'l' 
  AND nb <= '5'
```

and compare the output with the `742873` you have from the spatial index.

Comment: I thought about using multiple column index before too, but I am not sure whether it would compromise my insert query speed. So I am taking one step at a time by examining which single column index performs fastest. I do expect spatial index having high cardinality to perform better. But I don't expect it to rely so much on cache for its speed. Would I face similar cache problem if I use the above multiple column indices?

Comment: It depends on how often the table is updated (rows INSERTed, UPDATEd, DELETEd). Regarding the insert query speed, you might consider splitting the table into an InnoDB one with all the data except the spatial and a MyISAM one with the spatial data+index.

Comment: I get what you mean. The smaller number of rows examined, the faster the query. I will try that and let you know the result tomorrow. Thanks for your patience and kind assistance on the subject matter. **=)**

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and checked the select count(*) for the three cases to be 161341, 57324 and 137262 respectively. I built a four-column index for the **first case** and ran the query which produces a query time of **160sec** on the first run. Using a **full table scan**, i.e. ignoring the index, I can get a query time of **7.7sec** on the first run. I believe the time will not be reduced dramatically for the other two indices even with higher selectivity. Do I proceed to add a five-column or six-column index or is a full table scan the way to go?